# How to write a tab-delimited file when the tab-delimiter comes from a database?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a problem really phrasing this question so i try to give an example:

The following code works and creates the expected output: a delimited file where each column is separated by a "real" tab.

```
CSV.open(@targetfile, "wb", "\t") { |csv| 
csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", " }
```

The following code does not produce the expected out.

```
CSV.open(@targetfile, "wb", @targetdelimiter) { |csv| 
csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"] }
```

`@targetdelimiter` in this case comes from the database and is actually the string `'\t'` (without the quotes) which can be configured by the user.

This code produces also a delimited output, but i can see the `'\t'` instead of a "real" tab character.

What can I do with the second code block to get the same result as the first codeblock given that the `@targetdelimiter='\t'` from the db?

Comment: What you're really asking here is how to turn '\t' into "\t". That's quite an interesting question, and I can't immediately think of the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just gsub it and be done with it.

```
CSV.open(@targetfile, "wb", @targetdelimiter.gsub('\t',"\t")){ |csv| 
csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"] }
```

Comment: The important factor that's missing from the description is what other values @targetdelimiter might take. I'm assuming that there's a range of valid values, otherwise a trivial approach like this is obviously correct.

Comment: This does work with the usual suspects ',', ';', ' ', '|' and ,ehh, '/t'.

Comment: Yes, but you need a specific entry in the gsub call to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

`\t` is replaced by an actual tab character (ASCII `0x09`, or `Char(9)`) when it's used as a delimiter in your first example. In the second, it's not being replaced, and it's being used as the literal character sequence `\` and `t`. You might have luck if you don't have the users store the escape sequence, and instead use something like `TAB` or `NEWLINE`, which you can then read from the database and convert to the proper character instead (or you can just convert them from the literals to the proper character).